# I am new to react native , my project has multiple(9) image upload for every users ,as a result i have to upload images by compressing

Tags: javascript, react-native

My project contain 9 image upload for every user , So image before upload must be compressed by size keeping fixed the quality, but i do not want to use any library. can it is possible to compress the image programatically using javascript. and also want to know what should be the way for compressing before upload if user select multiple image during upload to server.please help i am very new to react native.

Comment: In the browser, you can do this by adding images to canvas and then upload canvas. But react native don't have canvas but you can use canvas in Webview. I hadn't never done that before but it worth it to  try

Comment: if react native don't have it , then how can i do this , please help if any other solutions

Comment: well like my comment, you can use canvas in react-native-webview. Basically, it's a browser